# Limit question please math help?

Tags: limits

I have to find $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^{x+1}+3^{x+1}}{2^x-3^x}$$
.... so I thought first about separating them..and then factor what ? can you tell me just the start please?

Comment: Limit as $x$ approaches what?

Comment: Also, please note that both you and the site would benefit if you would [register your account.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account)

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{2^{x+1}+3^{x+1}}{2^x-3^x}=3\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x+1}+1}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x-1}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}3\frac{0+1}{0-1}=-3$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^{x+1}+3^{x+1}}{2^x-3^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\cdot (2/3)^x+3}{(2/3)^x-1}=-3$$
since $\lim_{x\to \infty}a^x=0,$ if $|a|<1$